# VS2010 upgrade with UnitTestFramework

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am having an issue with upgrading from VS2008 to VS2010 and staying with .Net 3.5.

All my unit test projects as soon as I open them in VS2010 have their assembly references replaced from v9 to v10. This causes the build to fail because my projects are built in .Net 3.5.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

Replaced with:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

In order to fix this, I have to manually edit the assembly reference to point to V9 every time I open the solution.

Has anyone had this issue ? Any solutions ?

Comment: Hmm.. why build tests for 3.5? It's not like you're shipping them! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with VS2010.  If you go into your unit test project properties, the target framework dropdown will only have one choice: .Net 4

This was fixed with SP1.  If you install SP1 and go into project properties you should be able to target .Net 3.5 with your unit test project.